# Installing ruby-debug19 for ruby 1.9.3p125 without RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm attempting to get ruby-debug19 gem installed on an ubuntu box. I'm aware that two of the dependencies are linecache19 and ruby-debug-19, and that the versions up on rubygems are not yet compatibly with the latest release of ruby.

I've found this gist https://gist.github.com/1333785 which describes what I need to do, and I've got this working on my local computer with RVM. However, on this box I've compiled ruby from source and am not using RVM.

I've attempted to install the gems like so
`gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=/usr/local/bin/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include`

But that fails with the error below. I've noticed that the include directory in RVM is much different than the one in my linux box as well...

```
gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=/usr/local/bin/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed linecache19-0.5.13
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/bin/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-ruby-include=/usr/local/bin/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
    --with-ruby-dir
    --without-ruby-dir
    --with-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
    --with-ruby-lib
    --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
extconf.rb:16:in `block in <main>': break from proc-closure (LocalJumpError)
    from /usr/local/bin/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:18:in `call'
    from /usr/local/bin/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:18:in `create_makefile_with_core'
    from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What were the commands that you used to compile it from source?

Comment: ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/bin/ruby-1.9.3-p125 --enable-pthread --enable-shared, then ran make and make install

Comment: What does the mkmf.log file tell you?